# Updating Primary Key value Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, primary-key, cql

I have table with node_id, node_name and data. My requirement is to getByID and getByName. So I have made id and name as the primary keys. But I also need to sometimes update the name as well.

I know Cassandra does not allow updating primary keys and having non primary key in the WHERE clause.

How can I achieve this?

I did consider deleting the record first, and then inserting again with the same id and new name. But I read that this would create tombstones and affect the performance.

Answer (score 1):

Use only node_id as the primary key. To implement getByName create a materialized view. [materialized views in cassandra](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/new-in-cassandra-3-0-materialized-views)

Answer (score -1):

```
    create table users_by_id_name(
        id int,
        createdOn bigint, -- timestamp in millisec
        name text,
        age int, 
        primary key (id,name,createdOn)
    )WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY ( name DESC, createdOn DESC);
```

Use above table definition to insert users. 
Insert query --

```
insert into users_by_id_name (id,createdOn,name,age) values (1,100,'darthvedar',28);
```

to update the user, insert the row again with same user id and updated name and createdOn value.

```
insert into users_by_id_name (id,createdOn,name,age) values (1,200,'obi-wan-kenobi',28);
```

while selecting the user use below query --

select by user id -

```
select * from users_by_id_name where id=1 limit 1;
```

Select user by name -

```
select * from users_by_id_name where name='obi-wan-kenobi' ALLOW FILTERING;
```

Other way is to use secondary index on user name. Think, user name is not going to change too frequently, so secondary index is also one good option.

Edit after comments -

If you have very frequent updates on user name, it would be better to use two different tables.

```
   create table users_by_id(
    id int,
    name text,
    age int, 
    primary key (id)
);
   create table users_by_name(
    id int,
    name text,
    age int, 
    primary key (name)
);
```

While inserting , insert in both the tables using batch statement.

Hope this will help.

Comment: "to update the user, insert the row again with same user id and updated name and createdOn value." - You are inserting a new combination of primary keys. This will create a new entry in the table. It will not update the existing entry.
This will be a problem when you want to fetch all the all the entries.
Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Yes, thats why we are using limit 1 in our query, so that it will take latest entry.

Comment: I don't think this is a good approach when you have millions of records and updating them which will create heaps of unwanted data.

Comment: Yes, thats what cassandra is for, and I dont think user name is going to change every day for every user. Its like once in a year change for one user (may be).

Comment: I don't have a user table. I'm sorry if the column 'age' mislead you. I was just using a mock table to explain things easier. Adding duplicate records will be problem, when I try to fetch all the records from the table.

Comment: That's the thing, we cannot generalize cassandra modelling. Its like solution to a problem approach.  You could have explained the exact problem.

Comment: It looks to me like @Sree has it figured out alright. Just use batch to delete and then reinsert your stuff. If this is really rare event you don't have to be afraid of the tombstones. Most of the time they are problem with massive deletes/TTL which does not look like your case. Had one cluster where I did delete then insert on primary key thing and I never run into trouble. For low frequency stuff you don't have to worry about tombstones.